# delete rows by aggregated values

Tags: t-sql, sql-delete

I have a table with detail rows. We want to make transactions for aggregated values from this table. There might be situations, where one row is positive and the another one negative. The aggregate is 0. I want to remove those rows.

Here is my example:

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE ( orderid INT
,                    account INT
,                    vatid   INT
,                    amount  DECIMAL(10,2)
,                    vat     DECIMAL(10,2) )

--test values
INSERT @tmp
VALUES ( 10001, 30500, 47, 175.50,  9.20  )
,      ( 10001, 30501, 47, 2010.60, 18.30 )
,      ( 10001, 30501, 47, 147.65,  8.05  )
,      ( 10001, 30502, 47, 321.15,  18.40 )
,      ( 10001, 30502, 47, 13.50,   0.95  )
,      ( 10001, 30510, 40, 15.00,   0.0   )
,      ( 10001, 30510, 40, -15.00,  0.0   )

--all rows
SELECT * FROM @tmp

--aggregate
  --aggregate for account 30510 is 0
SELECT tmp.orderid    
,      tmp.account    
,      tmp.vatid      
,      SUM(tmp.amount) [totalamount]
,      SUM(tmp.vat)    [totalvat]
FROM @tmp tmp
GROUP BY tmp.orderid
,        tmp.account
,        tmp.vatid

--delete rows with aggregated values 0
DELETE tmp
FROM @tmp tmp 
JOIN (
    SELECT ag.orderid
    ,      ag.account
    ,      ag.vatid
    FROM (
        SELECT tmp.orderid    
        ,      tmp.account    
        ,      tmp.vatid      
        ,      SUM(tmp.amount) [totalamount]
        ,      SUM(tmp.vat)    [totalvat]
        FROM @tmp tmp
        GROUP BY tmp.orderid
        ,        tmp.account
        ,        tmp.vatid
        ) ag
    WHERE ISNULL(ag.totalamount,0) = 0
        AND ISNULL(ag.totalvat,0) = 0
    )         tmp2
    ON tmp2.orderid = tmp.orderid
    AND tmp2.account = tmp.account
    AND tmp2.vatid = tmp.vatid

--check rows
SELECT * FROM @tmp
```

My code works and deletes rows with aggregated values of 0.

But it doesn't look very elegant. Is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Greetings Reto

Comment: Check if using `HAVING` helps, as I suggested below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [window function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql)

```
delete tt
from (  select sum(t.vat)    over (partition by t.orderid, t.account, t.vatid) as sumVat
             , sum(t.amount) over (partition by t.orderid, t.account, t.vatid) as sumAmt
          from @tmp t 
     ) tt 
where isnull(tt.sumAmt, 0) = 0 
  and isnull(tt.sumVat, 0) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

> Used `HAVING` at the earlier stage instead of `WHERE` at later stage. So query will filter out unwanted records right at grouping level and will still produce same results.

```
--delete rows with aggregated values 0
DELETE tmp
FROM @tmp tmp 
JOIN (
    SELECT ag.orderid
    ,      ag.account
    ,      ag.vatid
    FROM (
        SELECT tmp.orderid    
        ,      tmp.account    
        ,      tmp.vatid      
        -- Removed unwanted aggregates from select clause here
        FROM @tmp tmp
        GROUP BY tmp.orderid
        ,        tmp.account
        ,        tmp.vatid
        HAVING SUM(tmp.amount) = 0 -- This line is updated
        AND SUM(tmp.vat) = 0 -- This line is updated
        ) ag
        -- Removed WHERE clause from here and added HAVING above
    )         tmp2
    ON tmp2.orderid = tmp.orderid
    AND tmp2.account = tmp.account
    AND tmp2.vatid = tmp.vatid
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a common table expression to get only the rows that needs to be deleted, and then delete from the table using an inner join to the cte on the group by columns:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT tmp.orderid    
    ,      tmp.account    
    ,      tmp.vatid      
    FROM @tmp tmp
    GROUP BY tmp.orderid
    ,        tmp.account
    ,        tmp.vatid
    HAVING SUM(tmp.amount) = 0
    AND SUM(tmp.vat) = 0
)

DELETE t
FROM @Tmp as t
JOIN CTE ON t.orderid = cte.orderid
        AND t.account = cte.account
        AND t.vatid = cte.vatid
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/ZVG65589)